# How to get value from a model`s recursive function after few iterations in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, recursion

I have a function that search category_id of top level parent category.
But after 1 iteration it doesn`t return value to a controller.

Controller:

```
$top_parent = $this->catalog_model->top_parent($catalog_id);
```

Model:

```
function top_parent($category_id)
    {
        $data = $this->db->select('category_id, title, parent')
                         ->where('category_id',$category_id)
                         ->get('categories')
                         ->row_array();              

        if($data['parent'] == 0){
            return $data['category_id'];   
        }
        else{
            $this->top_parent($data['parent']);
        }

    }
```

How can I return found value to controller?

Comment: why are you calling this function recursively?

Comment: At first I check value of parent every time until get 0. Parent = 0 mean that this is top category and I can get it category_id. And for example I have category_id of subsubcategory. I need id of top. My table ('category_id', 'title', 'parent')

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple function instead of recursion. Dont do things with recursion what you can do with a simple query.

```
function top_parent($category_id)
{
    $data = $this->db->select('category_id')
                     ->where('category_id',$category_id)
                     ->where('parent',0)
                     ->get('categories')
                     ->row_array();              

    return $data['category_id']; 
}
```

Here only a where condition with parent = 0 is added

Comment: Thanks for Your answering! I have more difficult situation. I have just category_id of subcategory (or subsub etc.) and trying to get top category using value of parent. For example: Array ( [category_id] => 6 [title] => test [parent] => 5 ) Array ( [category_id] => 5 [title] => Sea aquas [parent] => 3 ) Array ( [category_id] => 3 [title] => Aquas [parent] => 0 )

Comment: in this situation use $this->sb->select_max('column') also read the active record class and please more clearify question i will answer soon

Comment: I just solve this. I had "return $this->top_parent($data['parent']);" after what it pass a new value to controller when id of parent become 0. Anyway, thank Your very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to go your way.. all you need to is to return the recursive call

```
function top_parent($category_id)
{
    $data = $this->db->select('category_id, title, parent')
                     ->where('category_id',$category_id)
                     ->get('categories')
                     ->row_array();              

    if($data['parent'] == 0){
        return $data['category_id'];   
    }
    else{
        return $this->top_parent($data['parent']); 
    }

}
```

Notice the line `return $this->top_parent($data['parent']);`

You should return here since the recursive call that will eventually meet the condition `$data['parent'] == 0` will actually return `$data['category_id'];` to the calling model function itself rather than the controller.